How to check if 2 doubles are relatively equal in C language?
I'm working on some old C code that checks if two doubles are relatively equal. It works most of the time but sometimes it says the 2 doubles aren't equal even though the Print statement shows they are equal. I assume there must be a very small difference that the print statement is not showing.
Here is the C code I'm working on. I was thinking I need to use a floor function that uses the precision value?
I'm sure there is a better way to do this in C++ but I have to keep it C based.
Any help would be much appreciated. TIA
// example function input
// double amount1 = 0.00015; double precision1 = 0.00001;
// double amount2 = 0.00015; double precision2 = 0.00001;

bool amountsEqual(const double amount1, const double precision1, const double amount2, const double precision2) {
    double amount = 0;

    if (amount1 > amount2) {
        amount = amount1 - amount2;
    } 
    else if (amount1 < amount2) {
        amount = amount2 - amount1;
    } 
    else {
        return true;
    }

    double precision = 0;

    if (precision1 <= precision2) {
        precision = precision1;
    } 
    else {
        precision = precision2;
    }

    if (amount <= precision)
        return true;

    printf("amount1: %lf amount2: %lf / precision1: %lf precision2: %lf / amount: %lf precision: %lf\n", amount1, amount2, precision1, precision2, amount, precision);

    return false;
}


Use %.17lf for the format specifier to see enough significant digits.

Ok I will add that... Thanks

Consider replacing much of your code with fabs

Note specifically the text in the marked duplicate “So, to get a proper answer, you must describe your situation more specifically.” Since there is no general solution, to get an answer for your specific situation, you would need to provide information on how the numbers to be compared by this function were produced, in what range of values they could be (and could have been involved in their production), and what the consequences are of accepting as equal numbers that would not be equal if calculated perfectly and of rejecting as equal numbers that would be equal.
